# Android Java class taking longer than expected to load. Can I alter my source to speed up?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I was wondering whether I could alter my code in any way to speed up the loading time. When the user wants to change an icon on their home screen, they click "select image" and choose my activity.

This is when the delay happens. It takes about 7 to 8 seconds to load. Now I do have 1,000 icons loading, BUT before I added the multiple gridviews it only took about 2 to 3 seconds. I added multiple gridviews so I could section off my icons, and I would like to keep that.

Here is the logcat when the icons2 class is loaded. I removed many of the GC_FOR_ALLOC entries because it was too big for this post.

I have looked at DDMS and compared the activity's allocation tracker with other themes that are quick and they are very close to the same. I am thinking I am doing more work than I need to in my `icons2` class, OR is it just not good practice to fill that many gridviews?

```
06-13 14:14:09.334: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 426K, 4% free 13815K/14352K, paused 10ms+0ms, total 15ms
06-13 14:14:09.525: W/Trace(1779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-13 14:14:09.535: W/Trace(1779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-13 14:14:09.535: W/Trace(1779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-13 14:14:09.557: W/Trace(1779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-13 14:14:09.595: W/Trace(1779): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-13 14:14:09.605: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1587K, 11% free 14168K/15868K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 11ms
06-13 14:14:09.655: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 732K, 12% free 14424K/16280K, paused 5ms, total 13ms
06-13 14:14:09.685: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 650K, 11% free 14804K/16572K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:09.705: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 731K, 12% free 15060K/16944K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-13 14:14:09.737: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 570K, 11% free 15435K/17152K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
06-13 14:14:09.905: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 650K, 11% free 15733K/17564K, paused 117ms, total 117ms
06-13 14:14:10.044: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 650K, 11% free 16032K/17856K, paused 129ms, total 129ms
06-13 14:14:10.104: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 650K, 11% free 16331K/18188K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:10.144: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 570K, 10% free 16675K/18480K, paused 4ms, total 5ms
06-13 14:14:10.214: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 650K, 11% free 16893K/18772K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:10.224: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 17154K/18980K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.265: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 17416K/19268K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
06-13 14:14:10.285: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 17677K/19516K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.304: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 17939K/19804K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.344: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 18200K/20052K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
06-13 14:14:10.364: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 18462K/20340K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
06-13 14:14:10.374: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 18724K/20588K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.414: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 10% free 18986K/20876K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
06-13 14:14:10.444: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 9% free 19247K/21124K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:10.464: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 9% free 19553K/21372K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.474: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 9% free 19733K/21660K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.514: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 489K, 9% free 20040K/21868K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:10.524: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 9% free 20221K/22156K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-13 14:14:10.564: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 488K, 9% free 20445K/22320K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:10.576: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 9% free 20669K/22528K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.614: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 488K, 9% free 20893K/22776K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
06-13 14:14:10.624: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 9% free 21117K/22984K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:10.666: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 491K, 9% free 21345K/23232K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
06-13 14:14:10.685: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 9% free 21569K/23480K, paused 6ms, total 7ms
06-13 14:14:10.714: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 488K, 8% free 21793K/23688K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:10.744: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 9% free 22017K/23936K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
06-13 14:14:10.756: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 406K, 8% free 22285K/24144K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
06-13 14:14:10.794: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 488K, 8% free 22509K/24436K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
06-13 14:14:10.804: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 8% free 22652K/24600K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
06-13 14:14:10.847: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 8% free 22920K/24808K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
06-13 14:14:10.865: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 8% free 23063K/25056K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
06-13 14:14:10.895: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 8% free 23249K/25140K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:10.924: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 406K, 8% free 23436K/25348K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
06-13 14:14:10.937: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 8% free 23623K/25556K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
06-13 14:14:11.065: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 406K, 8% free 23810K/25764K, paused 117ms, total 117ms
06-13 14:14:11.075: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 406K, 8% free 23997K/25932K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-13 14:14:11.085: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 8% free 24183K/26140K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:11.105: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 24414K/26308K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
06-13 14:14:11.335: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 8% free 24520K/26516K, paused 217ms, total 217ms
06-13 14:14:11.345: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 24669K/26600K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
06-13 14:14:11.355: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 24899K/26808K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:11.477: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 8% free 25005K/27016K, paused 103ms, total 103ms
06-13 14:14:11.485: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 25154K/27100K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:11.614: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 25304K/27264K, paused 116ms, total 116ms
06-13 14:14:11.624: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 326K, 8% free 25453K/27388K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:11.634: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 25603K/27552K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
06-13 14:14:11.654: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 25752K/27716K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
06-13 14:14:11.684: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 326K, 8% free 25901K/27880K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
06-13 14:14:11.696: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 7% free 26051K/28004K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-13 14:14:11.716: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 7% free 26200K/28168K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
06-13 14:14:11.744: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 326K, 7% free 26350K/28332K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
06-13 14:14:11.754: D/dalvikvm(1779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 26499K/28496K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
06-13 14:14:20.944: I/Choreographer(1779): Skipped 1161 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Here is my icons2 class

```
package bigdx.clean.multi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import bigdx.clean.multi.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Icons2 extends Activity {
    public Uri CONTENT_URI;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
        setContentView(R.layout.icon_picker);
        ExpandableHeightGridView g=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_folders);
        ExpandableHeightGridView g2=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_apps);
        ExpandableHeightGridView g3=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_google);
        ExpandableHeightGridView g4=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_system);
        ExpandableHeightGridView g5=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_games);
        ExpandableHeightGridView g6=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_text);
        g.setExpanded(true);
        g2.setExpanded(true);
        g3.setExpanded(true);
        g4.setExpanded(true);
        g5.setExpanded(true);
        g6.setExpanded(true);
        g.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
        g2.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
        g3.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
        g4.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
        g5.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
        g6.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
        g.setColumnWidth(iconSize);
        g2.setColumnWidth(iconSize);
        g3.setColumnWidth(iconSize);
        g4.setColumnWidth(iconSize);
        g5.setColumnWidth(iconSize);
        g6.setColumnWidth(iconSize);
        g.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
        g2.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
        g3.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
        g4.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
        g5.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
        g6.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
        g.setVerticalSpacing(iconSize/3);
        g2.setVerticalSpacing(iconSize/3);
        g3.setVerticalSpacing(iconSize/3);
        g4.setVerticalSpacing(iconSize/3);
        g5.setVerticalSpacing(iconSize/3);
        g6.setVerticalSpacing(iconSize/3);
        g.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g.getId()));
        g2.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g2.getId()));
        g3.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g3.getId()));
        g4.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g4.getId()));
        g5.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g5.getId()));
        g6.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g6.getId()));

        g.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        private Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + IconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                setResult(-1, new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(this.CONTENT_URI, str)));
                finish();
              }
    });
        g2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            private Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + IconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            setResult(-1, new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(this.CONTENT_URI, str)));
            finish();
        }
        });
        g3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            private Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + IconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            setResult(-1, new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(this.CONTENT_URI, str)));
            finish();
        }
        });
        g4.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            private Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + IconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            setResult(-1, new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(this.CONTENT_URI, str)));
            finish();
         }
        });
        g5.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            private Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + IconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            setResult(-1, new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(this.CONTENT_URI, str)));
            finish();
        }
        });
        g6.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            private Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + IconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    setResult(-1, new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(this.CONTENT_URI, str)));
                    finish();
                  }
        });
    }



    class IconsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private int mIconSize;
        private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;
        private int mG;

        public IconsAdapter(Context mContext, int iconsize, int g) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mIconSize = iconsize;
            this.mG = g;
                  loadIcons();
                }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mIconSize, mIconSize));
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }

        private void loadIcons() {

            final Resources resources = getResources();
            final String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();

            int folders = R.id.icon_grid_folders;
            int apps = R.id.icon_grid_apps;
            int system = R.id.icon_grid_system;
            int google = R.id.icon_grid_google;
            int text = R.id.icon_grid_text;
            int games = R.id.icon_grid_games;

            if (mG == folders) {
                mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_folders);
            }
            if (mG == apps) {
                mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_apps);
            }
            if (mG == games) {
                mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_games);
            }
            if (mG == text) {
                mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_text);
            }
            if (mG == google) {
                mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_google);
            }
            if (mG == system) {
                mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_system);
            }
        }
        private void addIcons(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
            final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
            for (String extra : extras) {
                int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
                if (res != 0) {
                    final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra,"drawable", packageName);
                    if (thumbRes != 0) {
                        mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you measured every step in your loading process? I would get Timestamps on different parts of the construction of your page and print them to the console to see where it's taking the longest. Do you need to have everything preloaded? I wonder if the icons can be loaded with some "lazy" loading pattern, but haven't tried such a thing in Android...